# Connecting to MS SQL Server using Windows authentication and JTDS

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jtds

I am unable to connect to SQL Server using Windows Authentification.
This is is the exception being thrown:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1889)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:587)
    ... 35 more
```

Here is the Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl(...);
    return dataSource;
  }
```

The following VM argument is defined:

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\x64\SSO
```

This points to **ntlmauth.dll** (from **jtds-1.3.1-dist.zip**)

The following dependency is defined in the pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.springsource.net.sourceforge.jtds</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Have obviously omitted something - any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Are you actually running with the 64 bit Java JRE

Comment: Thanks very much - changed VM argument to -Djava.library.path=C:\x86\SSO and it worked